# Circuit Diagram visualization framework for Java

Tags: java, frameworks, visualization

I am looking for a **framework to visualize Circuit Diagrams in Java application**.

I have to show Diagrams like that:

[image]

For one of my previous projects (in 2008 year) I used [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/). It worked well, but maybe somebody could propose more suitable for my needs framework? Does anyone have a similar task or know a good tools?

Also one of my tasks is to try to layout elements, because there is only info about connections in DB, but there is no layout information. I want to try to minimize manual layout work and looking for **layout algorithms**.

Thank you in advance.

PS: It is very desirable that the framework will be free.

PPS: Also I am interested in frameworks which can help to show (and edit) such type of diagrams using web browser.

Comment: Does it have to be a java program or could you just use a program already written for designing circuits?

Comment: For circuits I usually use fritzing http://www.fritzing.org/ its really useful and can also design pcbs and do breadboard type design

Comment: Thank you for your answer ghostbust555, but I was not so clear in my task and confused you. Really I have to show visualization inside of my program. I can use outside program to help me to make layout, but the main task is to show curcuit diagram inside of my program. You suggested me an interesting program, but unfortunately, it is not suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) is very similar to Jung. I haven't used it extensively but I evaluated both Jung and Prefuse for our graph application.

Another web based option is [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/) which I came across during my evaluation. You can draw interactive graphs with it but I suspect you might need layout information already available to use this tool. Anyway looks like the authors are moving to a new library named D3 so you can check that out.

Another option I see is [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Here is a big list of graph visualization tools. http://www.mkbergman.com/414/large-scale-rdf-graph-visualization-tools/

Answer (score -2):

I found a java framework named circuit. I think it could help you fix your issue.
http://code.google.com/p/circuit-framework/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that project has nothing to do with circuit diagrams. I half suspect it is a satirical joke about Java framework projects - it doesn't actually describe what it does anywhere on their website, nor does the example even show anything of value.